# HTML formatting: can't do properly separated text

Tags: html

I'm trying to do some text displaying, but sometimes there are many items to display. The problem is that for each item, I have to display a sprite (= just a portion of a big picture).

The code which displays the sprite looks like:

```
<span style="display:block; 
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    background: url('/lol/img/sprite/item1.png') -96px -384px no-repeat;"
>&nbsp;</span>
```

The problem I'm facing, is for big screens: when the text is too short, the next "item" goes "into" the previous, like this (watch it on a 1920px wide screen: http://www.wogwog.fr/champions/amumu/)

How should I do to make it always appear like "one picture+description on the right", one line by one line (just resize your browser to a smaller width to see a "proper" display)?

Sorry I'm not very good in CSS & in english...

Comment: Add `clear:left`. When learning about something (in this case, `float`), learn ALL of it, not just the first thing that comes to you, then you might be able to use it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem which you mention is solvable by using [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) on div which encloses this span. This will prevent any other floating element placed after clearfixed one to collide with it.

Clearfix simply pushes invisible table element right after `container`.

```
.container:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: According to SO rules link-only answers are not acceptable. Could you elaborate?